# Unique node connected to user - Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a functioning app where users can signup/login, upload images and view images that have already been uploaded. However when an image is shared it shows up for every user and I want the images to be user-specific (you can only see the images that you uploaded). I can't quite get the rules right on storage and realtime database. Here are my rules for realtime database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the rules for firebase storage:

```
rules_version = '1';
service firebase.storage {
    match /users/{userid} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId; 
    }
}
```

Here is the code for uploading image.

```
    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri uri){

        //StorageReference fileRef = reference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(uri));
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            StorageReference fileRef = reference
                    .child(uid)
                    .child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(uri));

            fileRef.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            Model model = new Model(uri.toString());
                            String modelId = root.push().getKey();
                            root.child(modelId).setValue(model);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_photo_alternate_24);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Failed !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my code for the show images activity.

```
package com.example.auth;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Model> list;

    private MyAdapter adapter;

    private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Image");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this , list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                    list.add(model);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Using these rules, when I try to upload an image I get the logcat error "StorageException has occurred. User does not have permission to access this object." Any insight as to why this is happening and how to correct my rules would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is spelling mistake in userId and userid

Comment: If the typo that @gulabpatel pointed out is not the problem, please edit your question to [show the minimal, complete/standalone source with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing that, it's typically hard to troubleshoot security rules problems.

Comment: @gulabpatel corrected the spelling, still doesn't work same error.

Comment: I've added the code for more context @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `reference` like this:

```
private StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```

Then you try to upload a file with:

```
StorageReference fileRef = reference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(uri));
fileRef.putFile(uri)....
```

To the path you try to upload to is `/$time+$extension`, which does not include any user identification. Since your security rules only allow the user to put files under their own UID, they reject the upload.

To upload under the current user's UID:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
  StorageReference fileRef = reference
    .child(uid)
    .child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(uri));
  ...
}
```

Comment: Tried it (updated code to what I tried) however still getting the same problem

Comment: I've tested again by setting storage rules to public, realtime database write works, read doesn't work. If I put the storage rules back in nothing works.

Comment: Is the explanation of why you can't write a file with your current code/rules in my answer clear? If so, does the change make sense? "still getting the same problem" seems quite unlikely after that fix, although it is of course always possible I have a mistake in my answer. Are you getting the exact same error message?

Comment: I understand what you mean, I think I just need to do a similar thing (adding uid) with the "show all" activity's code. I am experimenting with it right now to no avail, so I've added the code to my question too.

Comment: That just broadens the problems further. I am trying to focus on a single problem: the writing of the file to storage, which is being rejected by your rules because you're not specifying a UID in the path. My answer shows how to include the UID in the path. After that, the file write should no longer be rejected by your rules. Nothing else should change. --- What error message do you get after making the change from my answer?

Comment: I mentioned above that the write works, so the code you gave me is fine, however the read is in a separate activity so I also have to edit the code for that.